# What is the best practice for backing up All my git repos backup on s3?

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using **bitbucket cloud** as my git host and I have around 200 repos.
I wish to backup **all my repos** including (all branches) on AWS S3 bucket daily.

We are several people who works on the same account ( 100+ repos) although no one have the permission to delete a repo we can all delete the content of a repo by making `git reset --hard <init_commit>` and then `git push --force`. according to [bitbucket backup](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/does-bitbucket-backup-my-repositories/) we observe that there is no auto backup therefore I wish to create one

I thought of using AWS code builder for it but if I understand from the docs correctly, it is only for 12 repos max for project.

As I am sure I am not the first person who try solve it, I am trying to understand what is the best practice for such a requirement?

The default, which I hope to avoid would be a lambda+ bitbucket api + cloud watch.

Thx in advance

Comment: 1. Why keep history? That's what git is for. 2. Why not use bitbucket's own backup tools?

Comment: ```Our backups are for disaster recovery purposes only. We are not able to use our backups to restore repositories that have been deleted by an end-user.```.               1. We are few people that have full access, if one chose ( no one can delete a repo) one can delete the content of all repos. 2. I didnt know on such a tool do you have any  links?

Comment: [This](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/data-recovery-and-backups-776640050.html) has Atlassian's comparison on backup strategies and links to documentation on each. See the table at the bottom. Unless you're using their cloud solution, in which case I'm not sure that's relevant.

Comment: If you don't trust your colleagues, you can change permissions to only allow pushing to certain branches by certain people, or with approval. This is essentially what pull requests are for.

Answer (score 2):

A simple approach for backup is to use [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle): that produces *one* file per repository (with all their history and branches)

Once you have those files locally, you can then save them to S3: one file per repo is easier/quicker to save/sync than pushing lots of small files.

Comment: This differ from third-party backup service like https://github.com/marketplace/cloudback/

Comment: 1. github.com/marketplace/cloudback  seems to support only github repos. do you know any service similar that work with bitbucket? 2. regarding the ```git bundle``` it wont help if someone would do ``` git reset --hard *****``` and then ```git push --force```

Comment: @helpper 1. No. I was just mentioning cloudback as a thrif-party service example, but it is not free anyway, so it would (I suppose) not be a good solution in your case. 2. I use `git bundle` more as a way to take a snapshot of an existing repository, so it does not matter what kind of push was done to said repository.